# Reinstalling windows from usb

Tags: boot, operating-systems

I have a bootable usb and i want to reinstall windows on my PC. But I have a strange problem, this is my boot menu when usb isn't connected:

[image]

And this is boot menu when usb is connected (only one):

[image]

As you can see there are 3 new options, I tried selecting all of them one by one, but all booted to my current OS. I also tried using 2 different usb sticks and different ports. Any suggestions what should i do?

Motherboard is MSI MS-7369, running a AMD Athlon 64 x2 processor, AMI BIOS, this pc is old brought in 2007, only video card replaced, if that helps. Tried connecting the usb in front and back panels, same result.

Comment: We need hardware information.  Intel I believe has already removed the ability to boot to USB 2..0 devices 6th generation chipset.  Are you trying to use a card reader?  Be as specific as possible.

Comment: Updated the post

Comment: Try to install from an actual USB Flash drive instead of a card reader. I don't think the system will read the card reader correctly since it sees 3 different options, so it doesn't know where to pull the install files from.

Answer (score 0):

You should check the BIOS Boot configuration,
sometimes devices are disabled (you should see USB Hard Drive or USB Flash drive)
Also check the USB legacy support is enabled.

I've found the Motherboard manual here (if needed):
http://static.highspeedbackbone.net/pdf/MSI_MSI-K9N_NEO-F_V3_Manual.pdf